# Get a list of all links on a page?

Tags: categories

Is there someway to get a list of all links on a page, including links in theme files, header, footer, sidebar, posts, etc?

It is possible to do this in JavaScript, but I'm hoping for a server-side solution.

Answer (score 1):

it is possible to do on server side but you would have to create an [**output buffer**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and the either use [**Regex**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) or [**Dom phrase**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to get all of  the links.
a much easier solution would be to use JavaScript or even better jQuery.

Comment: Agreed, JS/jQuery is definately the favorable approach here.

Comment: I have a jQuery solution working at the moment, where I pass some links to the server with jquery.post(), get a new list of links as a response, and then modify the page. The major downside is there is no caching of these ajax requests. Is it possible to get this working to cache these requests with WP super cache?

Comment: Not really caching but you can save the links in the database before you return your respond, and next time just call that saved data.